# MVC 4 marcar todos los checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Buenos días,

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en mvc4 razor, y en una vista necesito mostrar una tabla. Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema viene cuando tengo que poner un `checkbox` en la cabecera y uno en cada elemento de la tabla y que el primer `checkbox` marque todos los demás.

La cabecera seria algo así:

```
@Html.CheckBox("ticTodos") &nbsp;Seleccionar</th>
```

y el cuerpo este:

```
<td class="text-center">@Html.CheckBox("ticDevolver")</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay diversas maneras de hacer funcionar esa característica, aquí te presento una haciendo uso de `JavaScript` puro:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="checkboxOptions">   
            @Html.CheckBox("CheckTodos", new { @onclick = "checkAll();" }) &nbsp;Seleccionar Todos
            <br />        
            @Html.CheckBox("CheckA") &nbsp;OpcionA
            <br />
            @Html.CheckBox("CheckB") &nbsp;OpcionB        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkAll() {
        var checkeado = document.getElementById('CheckTodos').checked;
        var checkBoxsList = document.getElementById('checkboxOptions').getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (checkeado) {
            for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxsList.length; i++) {
                checkBoxsList[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxsList.length; i++) {
                checkBoxsList[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias, me has ayudado a orientarme.